# How to utilize combo scoring in Corona?

Tags: coronasdk, scoring

i just have a quick question. Im playing around with Corona to try and get the look and feel of it and im currently editing some one else's sample code. I have added a scoring mechanism, and now i want to add a combo scoring mechanism so that when the user chops more than one fruit, i can add an extra 5 points. Its just that i have no idea how to start. If some one would point me in the right direction that would be great thank you. :)

Or if this would be much clearer: How about a function that will help me detect how many objects the user touches/slices in one touch/move?

```
require ("physics")
local ui = require("ui")

physics.start()
-- physics.setDrawMode ( "hybrid" ) -- Uncomment in order to show in hybrid mode    
physics.setGravity( 0, 9.8 * 2)

physics.start()

-- Audio for slash sound (sound you hear when user swipes his/her finger across the screen)
local slashSounds = {slash1 = audio.loadSound("slash1.wav"), slash2 = audio.loadSound("slash2.wav"), slash3 = audio.loadSound("slash3.wav")}
local slashSoundEnabled = true -- sound should be enabled by default on startup
local minTimeBetweenSlashes = 150 -- Minimum amount of time in between each slash sound
local minDistanceForSlashSound = 50 -- Amount of pixels the users finger needs to travel in one frame in order to play a slash sound

-- Audio for chopped fruit
local choppedSound = {chopped1 = audio.loadSound("chopped1.wav"), chopped2 = audio.loadSound("chopped2.wav")}

-- Audio for bomb
local preExplosion = audio.loadSound("preExplosion.wav")
local explosion = audio.loadSound("explosion.wav")

-- Adding a collision filter so the fruits do not collide with each other, they only collide with the catch platform
local fruitProp = {density = 1.0, friction = 0.3, bounce = 0.2, filter = {categoryBits = 2, maskBits = 1}}
local catchPlatformProp = {density = 1.0, friction = 0.3, bounce = 0.2, filter = {categoryBits = 1, maskBits = 2}}

-- Gush filter should not interact with other fruit or the catch platform
local gushProp = {density = 1.0, friction = 0.3, bounce = 0.2, filter = {categoryBits = 4, maskBits = 8} } 

-- Will contain all fruits available in the game 
local avalFruit = {}

-- Slash line properties (line that shows up when you move finger across the screen)
local maxPoints = 5
local lineThickness = 20
local lineFadeTime = 250
local endPoints = {}

-- Whole Fruit physics properties
local minVelocityY = 850
local maxVelocityY = 1100

local minVelocityX = -200
local maxVelocityX = 200

local minAngularVelocity = 100
local maxAngularVelocity = 200

-- Chopped fruit physics properties
local minAngularVelocityChopped = 100
local maxAngularVelocityChopped = 200

-- Splash properties
local splashFadeTime = 2500
local splashFadeDelayTime = 5000
local splashInitAlpha = .5
local splashSlideDistance = 50 -- The amoutn of of distance the splash slides down the background

-- Contains all the available splash images
local splashImgs = {}

-- Gush properties 
local minGushRadius = 10 
local maxGushRadius = 25
local numOfGushParticles = 15
local gushFadeTime = 500
local gushFadeDelay = 500

local minGushVelocityX = -350
local maxGushVelocityX = 350
local minGushVelocityY = -350
local maxGushVelocityY = 350

-- Timer references
local bombTimer
local fruitTimer

-- Game properties
local fruitShootingInterval = 1000
local bombShootingInterval = 5000

-- Groups for holding the fruit and splash objects
local splashGroup 
local fruitGroup 

local sampleVar = true 
local score = 0
local scoreText 


function main()

    score = 0
    display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )

    setUpBackground()

    scoreText = display.newText("Score: 0", 415, 100, native.systemFont, 50)
    scoreText:setTextColor(255, 255, 255)
    scoreText.text = ("Score: " )..score

    pauseAndResume ()
    setUpCatchPlatform()
    initGroups()
    initFruitAndSplash()


    Runtime:addEventListener("touch", drawSlashLine)
    timer.performWithDelay( 1000, displayScore)
    startGame()
end

function displayScore()

    scoreText.text = ("Score: " )..score
    score = score + 2


end


function startGame()

        shootObject("fruit")

        bombTimer = timer.performWithDelay(bombShootingInterval, function(event) shootObject("bomb") end, 0)
        fruitTimer = timer.performWithDelay(fruitShootingInterval, function(event) shootObject("fruit") end, 0)

end


-- Display the pause button
function pauseAndResume ()
    pausebutton = display.newImage ("paused2.png", 10, 100)

    pausebutton:addEventListener ("touch" , pauseGame)

    resumebutton = display.newImage ("resume.png", 10, 100)

    resumebutton.isVisible = false

    resumebutton:addEventListener ("touch", resumeGame)
end

function pauseGame (event)
    if (event.phase == "ended") then
        physics.pause ()
        pausebutton.isVisible = false
        resumebutton.isVisible = true
        timer.pause(fruitTimer)
        timer.pause(bombTimer)
        sampleVar = false
        return true
    end
end

function resumeGame (event)
    if (event.phase == "ended") then
        physics.start()
        pausebutton.isVisible = true
        resumebutton.isVisible = false
        timer.resume(fruitTimer)
        timer.resume(bombTimer)
        sampleVar = true
        return true
    end
end 

function initGroups()
     splashGroup = display.newGroup()
     fruitGroup = display.newGroup()
end

function setUpBackground()

    local background = display.newImage("bg.png", true)
    background.x = display.contentWidth / 2
    background.y = display.contentHeight / 2

end

-- Populates avalFruit with all the fruit images and thier widths and heights
function initFruitAndSplash()

    local watermelon = {}
    watermelon.whole = "watermelonWhole.png"
    watermelon.top = "watermelonTop.png"
    watermelon.bottom = "watermelonBottom.png"
    watermelon.splash = "redSplash.png"
    table.insert(avalFruit, watermelon)

    local strawberry = {}
    strawberry.whole = "strawberryWhole.png"
    strawberry.top = "strawberryTop.png"
    strawberry.bottom = "strawberryBottom.png"
    strawberry.splash = "redSplash.png"
    table.insert(avalFruit, strawberry)

    -- Initialize splash images
    table.insert(splashImgs, "splash1.png")
    table.insert(splashImgs, "splash2.png")
    table.insert(splashImgs, "splash3.png")
end


function getRandomFruit()

    local fruitProp = avalFruit[math.random(1, #avalFruit)]
    local fruit = display.newImage(fruitProp.whole)
    fruit.whole = fruitProp.whole
    fruit.top = fruitProp.top
    fruit.bottom = fruitProp.bottom
    fruit.splash = fruitProp.splash

    return fruit

end

function getBomb()

    local bomb = display.newImage( "bomb.png")
    return bomb
end

function shootObject(type)

    local object = type == "fruit" and getRandomFruit() or getBomb()

    fruitGroup:insert(object)

    object.x = display.contentWidth / 2
    object.y = display.contentHeight  + object.height * 2

    fruitProp.radius = object.height / 2
    physics.addBody(object, "dynamic", fruitProp)

    if(type == "fruit") then
        object:addEventListener("touch", function(event) chopFruit(object) end)
    else
        local bombTouchFunction
        bombTouchFunction = function(event) explodeBomb(object, bombTouchFunction); end
        object:addEventListener("touch", bombTouchFunction)
    end

    -- Apply linear velocity 
    local yVelocity = getRandomValue(minVelocityY, maxVelocityY) * -1 -- Need to multiply by -1 so the fruit shoots up 
    local xVelocity = getRandomValue(minVelocityX, maxVelocityX)
    object:setLinearVelocity(xVelocity,  yVelocity)

    -- Apply angular velocity (the speed and direction the fruit rotates)
    local minAngularVelocity = getRandomValue(minAngularVelocity, maxAngularVelocity)
    local direction = (math.random() < .5) and -1 or 1
    minAngularVelocity = minAngularVelocity * direction
    object.angularVelocity = minAngularVelocity

end


function explodeBomb(bomb, listener)

    bomb:removeEventListener("touch", listener)

    -- The bomb should not move while exploding
    bomb.bodyType = "kinematic"
    bomb:setLinearVelocity(0,  0)
    bomb.angularVelocity = 0

    -- Shake the stage
    local stage = display.getCurrentStage()

    local moveRightFunction
    local moveLeftFunction
    local rightTrans
    local leftTrans
    local shakeTime = 50
    local shakeRange = {min = 1, max = 25}

    moveRightFunction = function(event) rightTrans = transition.to(stage, {x = math.random(shakeRange.min,shakeRange.max), y = math.random(shakeRange.min, shakeRange.max), time = shakeTime, onComplete=moveLeftFunction}); end 
    moveLeftFunction = function(event) leftTrans = transition.to(stage, {x = math.random(shakeRange.min,shakeRange.max) * -1, y = math.random(shakeRange.min,shakeRange.max) * -1, time = shakeTime, onComplete=moveRightFunction});  end 

    moveRightFunction()

    local linesGroup = display.newGroup()

    -- Generate a bunch of lines to simulate an explosion
    local drawLine = function(event)

        local line = display.newLine(bomb.x, bomb.y, display.contentWidth * 2, display.contentHeight * 2)
        line.rotation = math.random(1,360)
        line.width = math.random(15, 25)
        linesGroup:insert(line)
    end
    local lineTimer = timer.performWithDelay(100, drawLine, 0)

    -- Function that is called after the pre explosion
    local explode = function(event)

        audio.play(explosion)
        blankOutScreen(bomb, linesGroup);
        timer.cancel(lineTimer)
        stage.x = 0 
        stage.y = 0
        transition.cancel(leftTrans)
        transition.cancel(rightTrans)

    end 

    -- Play the preExplosion sound first followed by the end explosion
    audio.play(preExplosion, {onComplete = explode})

    timer.cancel(fruitTimer)
    timer.cancel(bombTimer) 

end

function blankOutScreen(bomb, linesGroup)

    local gameOver = displayGameOver()
    gameOver.alpha = 0 -- Will reveal the game over screen after the explosion

    -- Create an explosion animation
    local circle = display.newCircle( bomb.x, bomb.y, 5 )
    local circleGrowthTime = 300
    local dissolveDuration = 1000

    local dissolve = function(event) transition.to(circle, {alpha = 0, time = dissolveDuration, delay = 0, onComplete=function(event) gameOver.alpha = 1 end}); gameOver.alpha = 1  end

    circle.alpha = 0
    transition.to(circle, {time=circleGrowthTime, alpha = 1, width = display.contentWidth * 3, height = display.contentWidth * 3, onComplete = dissolve})



end

function displayGameOver()

    -- Will return a group so that we can set the alpha of the entier menu
    local group = display.newGroup()

    -- Dim the background with a transperent square
    local back = display.newRect( 0,0, display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight )
    back:setFillColor(0,0,0, 255 * .1)
    group:insert(back)

    local gameOver = display.newImage( "gameover.png")
    gameOver.x = display.contentWidth / 2
    gameOver.y = display.contentHeight / 2
    group:insert(gameOver)  

    local replayButton = ui.newButton{
        default = "replayButton.png",
        over = "replayButton.png",
        onRelease = function(event) group:removeSelf(); main() ; end
    }
    group:insert(replayButton)



    replayButton.x = display.contentWidth / 2
    replayButton.y = gameOver.y + gameOver.height / 2 + replayButton.height / 2


    return group
end

-- Return a random value between 'min' and 'max'
function getRandomValue(min, max)
    return min + math.abs(((max - min) * math.random()))
end

function playRandomSlashSound()

    audio.play(slashSounds["slash" .. math.random(1, 3)])
end

function playRandomChoppedSound()

    audio.play(choppedSound["chopped" .. math.random(1, 2)])
end

function getRandomSplash()

    return display.newImage(splashImgs[math.random(1, #splashImgs)])
end

function chopFruit(fruit)

    if (sampleVar == true)  then


        displayScore() 
        playRandomChoppedSound()


        createFruitPiece(fruit, "top")
        createFruitPiece(fruit, "bottom")

        createSplash(fruit)
        createGush(fruit)

        fruit:removeSelf()


    end


end

-- Creates a gushing effect that makes it look like juice is flying out of the fruit
function createGush(fruit)

    local i
    for  i = 0, numOfGushParticles do
        local gush = display.newCircle( fruit.x, fruit.y, math.random(minGushRadius, maxGushRadius) )
        gush:setFillColor(255, 0, 0, 255)

        gushProp.radius = gush.width / 2
        physics.addBody(gush, "dynamic", gushProp)

        local xVelocity = math.random(minGushVelocityX, maxGushVelocityX)
        local yVelocity = math.random(minGushVelocityY, maxGushVelocityY)

        gush:setLinearVelocity(xVelocity, yVelocity)

        transition.to(gush, {time = gushFadeTime, delay = gushFadeDelay, width = 0, height = 0, alpha = 0, onComplete = function(event) gush:removeSelf() end})     
    end

end

function createSplash(fruit)

    local splash = getRandomSplash()
    splash.x = fruit.x
    splash.y = fruit.y
    splash.rotation = math.random(-90,90)
    splash.alpha = splashInitAlpha
    splashGroup:insert(splash)

    transition.to(splash, {time = splashFadeTime, alpha = 0,  y = splash.y + splashSlideDistance, delay = splashFadeDelayTime, onComplete = function(event) splash:removeSelf() end})       

end

-- Chops the fruit in half
-- Uses some trig to calculate the position 
-- of the top and bottom part of the chopped fruit (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotations_in_two_dimensions)
function createFruitPiece(fruit, section)

    local fruitVelX, fruitVelY = fruit:getLinearVelocity()

    -- Calculate the position of the chopped piece
    local half = display.newImage(fruit[section])
    half.x = fruit.x - fruit.x -- Need to have the fruit's position relative to the origin in order to use the rotation matrix
    local yOffSet = section == "top" and -half.height / 2 or half.height / 2
    half.y = fruit.y + yOffSet - fruit.y

    local newPoint = {}
    newPoint.x = half.x * math.cos(fruit.rotation * (math.pi /  180)) - half.y * math.sin(fruit.rotation * (math.pi /  180))
    newPoint.y = half.x * math.sin(fruit.rotation * (math.pi /  180)) + half.y * math.cos(fruit.rotation * (math.pi /  180))

    half.x = newPoint.x + fruit.x -- Put the fruit back in its original position after applying the rotation matrix
    half.y = newPoint.y + fruit.y
    fruitGroup:insert(half)

    -- Set the rotation 
    half.rotation = fruit.rotation
    fruitProp.radius = half.width / 2 -- We won't use a custom shape since the chopped up fruit doesn't interact with the player 
    physics.addBody(half, "dynamic", fruitProp)

    -- Set the linear velocity  
    local velocity  = math.sqrt(math.pow(fruitVelX, 2) + math.pow(fruitVelY, 2))
    local xDirection = section == "top" and -1 or 1
    local velocityX = math.cos((fruit.rotation + 90) * (math.pi /  180)) * velocity * xDirection
    local velocityY = math.sin((fruit.rotation + 90) * (math.pi /  180)) * velocity
    half:setLinearVelocity(velocityX,  velocityY)

    -- Calculate its angular velocity 
    local minAngularVelocity = getRandomValue(minAngularVelocityChopped, maxAngularVelocityChopped)
    local direction = (math.random() < .5) and -1 or 1
    half.angularVelocity = minAngularVelocity * direction
end

-- Creates a platform at the bottom of the game "catch" the fruit and remove it
function setUpCatchPlatform()

    local platform = display.newRect( 0, 0, display.contentWidth * 4, 50)
    platform.x =  (display.contentWidth / 2)
    platform.y = display.contentHeight + display.contentHeight
    physics.addBody(platform, "static", catchPlatformProp)

    platform.collision = onCatchPlatformCollision
    platform:addEventListener( "collision", platform )
end

function onCatchPlatformCollision(self, event)
    -- Remove the fruit that collided with the platform
    event.other:removeSelf()
end

-- Draws the slash line that appears when the user swipes his/her finger across the screen
function drawSlashLine(event)

    -- Play a slash sound
    if(endPoints ~= nil and endPoints[1] ~= nil) then
        local distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(event.x - endPoints[1].x, 2) + math.pow(event.y - endPoints[1].y, 2))
        if(distance > minDistanceForSlashSound and slashSoundEnabled == true) then 
            playRandomSlashSound();  
            slashSoundEnabled = false
            timer.performWithDelay(minTimeBetweenSlashes, function(event) slashSoundEnabled = true end)
        end
    end

    -- Insert a new point into the front of the array
    table.insert(endPoints, 1, {x = event.x, y = event.y, line= nil}) 

    -- Remove any excessed points
    if(#endPoints > maxPoints) then 
        table.remove(endPoints)
    end

    for i,v in ipairs(endPoints) do
        local line = display.newLine(v.x, v.y, event.x, event.y)
        line.width = lineThickness
        transition.to(line, {time = lineFadeTime, alpha = 0, width = 0, onComplete = function(event) line:removeSelf() end})        
    end

    if(event.phase == "ended") then     
        while(#endPoints > 0) do
            table.remove(endPoints)
        end
    end
end


main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Runtime touch listener ...in that listener event.phase == "move" you can do like above.In event.phase=="ended" reset the value.

Comment: Can you please expand your answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

Initial set some temp value.

```
Tempvalue=0   
function displayScore()   
if Tempvalue == 0 then
Tempvalue=Tempvalue+1
     score = score + 2
   scoreText.text = ("Score: " )..score   
else
    score = score + 5
   scoreText.text = ("Score: " )..score   
end
```

Comment: I dont seem to understand your answer, when do i reset the tempValue?

Comment: no need to reset.but other than that what is your problem in code?

Comment: Well, the game is kinda like fruit ninja. I want to add a combo where when the user chops more than one fruit, it will add 5 more points.

Answer (score 0):

I just put the sample how to do.

```
 temp=0
local newLine = function(event)


    if event.phase=="began" then

    elseif event.phase=="moved" then
        for i=1,3 do
            if event.target.name==i then
                temp=temp+1
                --here you can do your action to the object(like remove or score)
                print("touch"..temp)
            end
        end


    elseif event.phase=="ended" then

end

 return true
end
 for i=1,3 do
    local myCircle = display.newCircle( 100*i, 100, 9 )
    myCircle:setFillColor(128,128,128)
    myCircle.name=i
    myCircle:addEventListener("touch",newLine)

 end
```